# Django reverse foreign key values aggregate

Tags: django

I have two models,

```
class UploadedMedia(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    media_url = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class Account(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(
        blank=False,
        unique=True,
        db_index=True,
        max_length=255,
        help_text="Designates the email address and user name of the account.",
    )

    name = models.CharField(
        blank=True,
        unique=False,
        db_index=False,
        max_length=255,
        help_text="Designates the full name of the account.",
    )
```

I need to show max(created_at) for each record in Account model. Since it is a reverse foreign key I don't understand how can I achieve it. Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can access reverse relations by using the model name in lower case with `_set` appended so in your case you can write `uploadedmedia_set` to refer to the `UploadedMedia` of an `Account`.

```
from django.db.models import Max

result = Account.objects.annotate(max_created_at=Max('uploadedmedia_set__created_at'))
```

You can also set what name you want to use instead of this default by providing a [`related_name` [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) on your Foreign Key.

```
class UploadedMedia(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='uploaded_media')
    ...
```

Now you can write:

```
result = Account.objects.annotate(max_created_at=Max('uploaded_media__created_at'))
```

Now you can simply access this annotated result by writing something like `account.max_created_at` (`account` is an instance of `Account` from the queryset `result`).